# Having an Error: Element ref was specified as a string (container) but no owner was set. HOW do I solve?

Tags: reactjs, project-structure

I am attempting to build the correct react project structure to use to build a temperature converter.

**problem - I keep getting the following error each time I attempt to render JSx via a class component:**

```
Error: Element ref was specified as a string (container) but no owner was set. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You may be adding a ref to a functional component
2. You may be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method
3. You have multiple copies of React loaded
```

How do I correct this issue?

**Tree structure for the configuration and source directory:**

```
configuration
├── index.html
├── main.css
└── main.js
source
├── InteractiveModel.js
├── components
│   └── CelsiusComponent.js
├── css
│   └── main.css
├── index.html
└── index.js
```

The sets of code that I think is causing the error are :

**CelsiusComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-grid-system';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';

const style = {
    margin: 12,
  };
class CelsiusComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props) 
        // Set initial state 
        this.state = {InputUser:''};
    }
    ManageMutation(event) {
        const InputUser = event.target.value;
        this.setState({InputUser})
    } 
    resetInputField() {
        this.setState({InputUser:''})
    }
render() {
    const InputUser = this.state.InputUser;
    let result;
    if (!InputUser) {
        result=''
    } else {
      result =(InputUser-32)*5/9
    }
        const MaterialInterface = 
        <MuiThemeProvider>
                <Container>

                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={4}>
                    <h3>
                        Enter Temperature in Fahrenheit 
                        </h3>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>


                    <Row>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                        <TextField 
                        type='text' 
                        floatingLabelText="Enter  Number "
                        value =
                        {this.state.InputUser} 
                        onInput =
                        { this.ManageMutation = this.ManageMutation.bind(this)} 
                        />
                        </Col>
                        </Row>


                        <Row>
                                        <Col sm={4}>
                                        <p>Temperature in Celsius</p>
                                        </Col>
                         </Row>
                                <Row>
                                        <Col sm={4}>
                                        <p>{result}</p>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>

                        <Row>
                           <Col sm={4}>
                                    {/* <RaisedButton 
                                    label=" Default "/> */}
                                    <RaisedButton  onClick =
                                    {this.resetInputField=this.resetInputField.bind(this)} label="Delete" style={style} />
                       </Col>
                        </Row>


            </Container>
            </MuiThemeProvider>

        return MaterialInterface
    }
}
export default CelsiusComponent;
```

**InteractiveModel.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import CelsiusComponent from './components/CelsiusComponent';
class  InteractiveModel extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div className='iteractive-model'>
           <CelsiusComponent   />
    </div>
  );
}
};
export default InteractiveModel;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import style from "./css/main.css";
import InteractiveModel from "./InteractiveModel";
render(<InteractiveModel />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: since i'm not seeing any `ref`s in code, i'm assuming #3 applies to you; have you tried `npm ls react` to see if you have multiple copies installed?

Comment: @Napoli Yes I have. It returned `└── react@16.3.0 `